# move between pages when pages are events

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale_women'
#prod=response.css('.lazyload')
#next_page =
```

Hello, I am trying to move between the pages however,the pages are "Events" and it simply adds "#pageno=2&pageSize=120&filter=price:0,250" when going to next page, How can I move to next page (to fetch the products links) using scrapy or requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forever21 has a json endpoint with the product data.
You don't even need to do pagination, just increase the page size.

[image: network tab]

Comment: Can you please add to answer how to do it using `scrapy.FormRequest`

Comment: Don't use that. Use requests.post()